# Errors with #define

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants, c-preprocessor

I have a file that has many `#define` statements such as -

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H
#define BUMP 7;
#define WHEEL_DROPS 7;
#define WALL 8;
#define CLIFF_LEFT 9;
#define CLIFF_FRONT_LEFT 10;
#define CLIFF_FRONT_RIGHT 11;
#define CLIFF_RIGHT 12;
#define VIRTUAL_WALL 13;
...
... 
#endif
```

The list goes on to about 42 different values. I include this file into my other files, but whenever I try to use one of these constants I get errors. For a specific example, I try to do -

```
Sensor_Packet temp;
temp = robot.getSensorValue(BUMP); //line 54
cout<<temp.values[0]<<endl;
```

The errors I get are -

```
main.cpp:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
main.cpp:54: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
main.cpp:54: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

I don't see why I am getting these errors because BUMP is already defined. This also happens when I try to use a switch statement with the cases being the defines -

```
switch(which) {
case BUMP:
    //do stuff
case CLIFF_LEFT:
   //do stuff
}
```

Is there something I am leaving out about using `#define`? I thought all I had to do was define a constant and then I could just call it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This just appeared on the question about favorite one-line C++ bugs (yesterday?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a closer look at your `#define`s:

```
#define BUMP 7;
```

This tells the preprocessor to replace `BUMP` with `7;`. Note that the macro definition includes the semicolon!

So your code actually looks like this to the compiler:

```
Sensor_Packet temp;
temp = robot.getSensorValue(7;);
cout<<temp.values[0]<<endl;

// ...

switch(which)
{
case 7;:
    // do stuff
case 9;:
    //do stuff
}
```

Which are clearly syntax errors. To fix this, remove the semicolons in your `#define` statements.

But in C++, you should be using `const int`s or [`enum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages)s for constants instead of `#define`s. Here are some possible examples:

```
enum CliffPositions
{
    CLIFF_LEFT  = 9,
    CLIFF_FRONT_LEFT = 10,
    CLIFF_FRONT_RIGHT = 11,
    CLIFF_RIGHT = 12,
};

enum WallType
{
    WALL = 8,
    VIRTUAL_WALL = 13;
}

const int BUMP = 7;
const int WHEEL_DROPS = 7;

// etc ...
```

This way is preferable because unlike `#define`s, `const int`s and `enum`s respect scope and are more type-safe.

Comment: (+1) To clarify: remove the `;` after all your `#define` statements

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colons and you should be good to go.